# Changing ng-class of current element in execution

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a form which gets generated at runtime. I'm trying to update the class of the input box if validation fails. I'm performing validation on `ng-blur = "chaeckValidation()"` Now if I'm using `ng-class = "active"` and set the variable in controller for `$scope.active = "has-error-class"`.

What this is doing is updating class of all the elements in form to `error-class css` but I want to attach `error-class css` only to the element which failed validation.

I tried but couldn't find any success. I can't hardcode anything in form as the form is completely dynamic and moreover I'm performing validation through `regular expression` in function and want to display error message based on which `regular expression` failed.

Code:
prop.json

```
[ 
 { label      : Application Name
   cid        : uniqueId
   typeApex   : CURRENCY
   fieldPath  : application_Name__c
   type       : NUMBER
   value      : ''
   dbRequired : true
   isRequired : false
 },
 {...similar array of JSON object ...},
 {}
]
```

view.html

```
<div ng-if="prop.type != 'picklist' && prop.type != 'reference'">
  <label for="{{prop.label}}">{{prop.label}}</label>
  <input type="{{prop.type}}" id="inputFields{{prop.fieldPath}}" ng-blur="fieldValidation(prop.fieldPath, prop.typeApex, $event)" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"  
         class="form-control" name="{{prop.fieldPath}}" ng-model="fieldPathValue[prop.fieldPath]" 
         ng-required="isRequired({{prop.dbRequired}}, {{prop.required}})" ng-class ="active"/> 
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.fieldValidation = function(fieldPath, type, $event) {
  console.log('fieldPath in fieldValidation ',fieldPath);
  var myMap = new Map();
  myMap.set("Term__c","^[0-9]+$");
  myMap.set("Loan_Amount__c","[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?");
  //console.log("fieldPathValue ",$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify($scope.fieldPathValue)));
  //console.log("fieldPathValue ",$scope.fieldPathValue);
  var value = $event.target.value;
  console.log("value ",value);
  var reg = new RegExp(myMap.get(fieldPath));

  console.log("regex test result ",reg.test(value));

  console.log("event ",$event);
  if(!reg.test(value)) {
    //add error message classs to selected field
    //display error message on top of field

     $timeout(function(){
       $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.active = "has-error";
         }); 
     }, 0);

  }
```

Result Image:

[image]

I have made an error in first input field which accepts float numbers and I have provided alphabets, so it throws error but that error is propogated to entire form and not only to the element which triggers it.

How can I make sure only element that `fails validation on ng-blur` gets the error-class-css attached.

I have tried doing this using `getElementById` but no success. Added the questions link below.

I have described more on my questions form element in one of my questions. [DOM elements not getting updated from angular controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894762/dom-elements-not-getting-updated-from-angular-controller)

Comment: use directive(s) and require ngModel then you can work with the angular validation api. Lots of tutorials around for custom validation done this way

Comment: I tried to make my design around directives but I'm not sure if directives are right choice for what I'm trying to do here. My regular expression will be fetched from server when a particular page loads and then whatever element are present on that page will be checked against those regular expression. Directives are static,one time thing things as per my understanding and using them to validate dynamic forms, I just don't know how to proceed. It would be a great help if you could point some direction.

Comment: take a look at how modules like angular-formly do this sort of thing. There are several different dynamic form modules around such as that one